# pgfplots - number format on axis

Tags: pgfplots

How can I force pgfplots to draw my axis ticks labels consistently? I mean instead of 0 a 0.0, instead of 1 a 1.0 in the below image.

[image]

**EDIT: Code**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\pgfplotsset{
compat=1.7,
every axis/.append style={
line width=1.25pt,
tick style={line width=1.25pt, color=black, line cap=round}
}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  enlarge x limits=0.05,
  enlarge y limits=0.05,
  try min ticks=4,
  max space between ticks=50pt,
  y tick label style={
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    fixed,
    fixed zerofill,
    precision=1
  },
  x tick label style={
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    fixed,
    fixed zerofill,
    precision=2
  }
]
\addplot[red] table[x index=1,y index=7] {dataA.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I can't attach the data file, so here's a [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19186705/dataA.dat).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can change the number format using the `/pgf/number format` keys (there are a *lot* of options). In this concrete case, you'll want to set `fixed`, `fixed zerofill`, `precision=1` for the y axis, and `precision=2` for the x axis:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=1,
        /tikz/.cd
    },
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=2,
        /tikz/.cd
    }
]
\addplot [domain=0.98:1.02] {rnd};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll get an error. This is, I guess, due to the numbers are very small. They have the expansion 1e-19 or something. Is there a way to deal with that?

Comment: @DaPhil: Sorry, I forgot to change the key directory back using `/tikz/.cd` (PGFPlots was still trying to apply normal `tikz` options using the `/pgf/number format` directory. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a comma `,` after `precision=2`.

Comment: @Jake: When and why do we need the change directory key `/tikz/.cd`? The manual (v1.9 §4.4/p.74) states something else...

Comment: @strpeter: You need to change the directory key back using `/tikz/.cd` if you later want to apply other options to the labels that don't belong to the `/pgf/number format` directory (e.g. adding `x tick label style=red` later on). That's not the case in this code example, but resetting the directory to `/tikz` anyway can't hurt.

Comment: @Jake Do you think it should be mentioned that this approach does not work for `loglogaxis` axis environments?