# Problem with tikz : alignment of figure when using bracket in xlabel

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, subfloats, brackets

When I put bracket in a xlabel, the alignement of my figure change. It's just a little move, but it's uggly because i put two sub figures side by side.

Do you know how to solve this ?

Thanks in advance,

Thomas

PS : I think [Here :](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134555/tikz-graph-not-aligning) [TikZ graph not aligning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134555/tikz-graph-not-aligning) is the same problem, but unresolved.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45 \textwidth}
\caption{sub-figure 1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\begin{axis}[height=\textwidth,width=\textwidth,
axis lines=left, enlarge x limits=true, enlarge y limits=true,
xlabel={x},
scaled x ticks = false,
ylabel={y},
x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/1000 sep = \thinspace},
]
\addplot[ybar,ybar interval=0] coordinates{
(0,8) (500,87) (1000,127) (1500,93) (2000,68) (2500,51) (3000,40) (3500,17) (4000,19) (4500,14) (5000,11)                   (5500,2) (6000,1) (6500,1) (7000,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
~
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45 \textwidth}
\caption{sub-figure 2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\begin{axis}[height=\textwidth,width=\textwidth,
axis lines=left, enlarge x limits=true, enlarge y limits=true,
xlabel={x {(test)}},
scaled x ticks = false,
ylabel={x},
x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/1000 sep = \thinspace},
]
\addplot[ybar,ybar interval=0] coordinates{
(0,8) (500,87) (1000,127) (1500,93) (2000,68) (2500,51) (3000,40) (3500,17) (4000,19) (4500,14) (5000,11)                   (5500,2) (6000,1) (6500,1) (7000,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{subfigure} 
\end{figure}
\vfill
\end{document}
```

Comment: To x label of the first sub figure add \vphantom{)}.

Comment: it is a cheat! But it's work ! ^^ Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to fix this:

1. As per Zarko's comment you can add a `xlabel={$x$ \vphantom{(test)}}`. The reason is the initial mismatch was the additional height of the `(`. Adding a `\vphantom` ensures that the both labels are of the same height. You actually on need a `\vphantom{(}`, but in other cases you may need the full text of the other label.
2. Add a `strut` as in `xlabel={$x$\strut}`.  The `\strut` should be added to *both* of the labels.
3. Specify a style for the `xlabel` which positions the label correctly (as in the MWE below).

   [image]

### Notes:

- Axis labels should probably be in math mode as per the MWE below.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45 \textwidth}
\caption{sub-figure 1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\begin{axis}[height=\textwidth,width=\textwidth,
axis lines=left, enlarge x limits=true, enlarge y limits=true,
xlabel={$x$},
scaled x ticks = false,
ylabel={$y$},
x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/1000 sep = \thinspace},
xlabel style={at={(0.5,0)}, below,yshift=-25pt, anchor=base, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=2.0ex}
]
\addplot[ybar,ybar interval=0] coordinates{
(0,8) (500,87) (1000,127) (1500,93) (2000,68) (2500,51) (3000,40) (3500,17) (4000,19) (4500,14) (5000,11)                   (5500,2) (6000,1) (6500,1) (7000,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
~
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45 \textwidth}
\caption{sub-figure 2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\begin{axis}[height=\textwidth,width=\textwidth,
axis lines=left, enlarge x limits=true, enlarge y limits=true,
xlabel={$x$ (test)},
scaled x ticks = false,
ylabel={$x$},
x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/1000 sep = \thinspace},
xlabel style={at={(0.5,0)}, below,yshift=-25pt, anchor=base, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=2.0ex}
]
\addplot[ybar,ybar interval=0] coordinates{
(0,8) (500,87) (1000,127) (1500,93) (2000,68) (2500,51) (3000,40) (3500,17) (4000,19) (4500,14) (5000,11)                   (5500,2) (6000,1) (6500,1) (7000,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{subfigure} 
\end{figure}
\vfill
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer. I prefer the solution 2, it's easier.

Comment: In your `xlabel style`, `anchor=base` is preferable to `anchor=center`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Thanks. I knew there was something better than `center` but couldn't remember at the time -- must be getting old. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A label generally fit on one line. So you can set the height and depth of the text for all axis labels:

```
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.11,
  label style={text height=.8em,text depth=.15em},
}
```

With this style, your figures are correctly aligned (horizontally and vertically) and labels use the same `baseline`.

Your MWE, completed:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.11,
  label style={text height=.8em,text depth=.15em},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45 \textwidth}
    \caption{sub-figure 1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
      \begin{axis}[height=\textwidth,width=\textwidth,
        axis lines=left, enlarge x limits=true, enlarge y limits=true,
        xlabel={x},
        scaled x ticks = false,
        ylabel={y},
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/1000 sep = \thinspace},
        ]
        \addplot[ybar,ybar interval=0] coordinates{
          (0,8) (500,87) (1000,127) (1500,93) (2000,68) (2500,51) (3000,40) (3500,17) (4000,19) (4500,14) (5000,11)                   (5500,2) (6000,1) (6500,1) (7000,0)};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{subfigure}
  ~
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45 \textwidth}
    \caption{sub-figure 2}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
      \begin{axis}[height=\textwidth,width=\textwidth,
        axis lines=left, enlarge x limits=true, enlarge y limits=true,
        xlabel={x {(test)}},
        scaled x ticks = false,
        ylabel={x},
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/1000 sep = \thinspace},
        ]
        \addplot[ybar,ybar interval=0] coordinates{
          (0,8) (500,87) (1000,127) (1500,93) (2000,68) (2500,51) (3000,40) (3500,17) (4000,19) (4500,14) (5000,11)                   (5500,2) (6000,1) (6500,1) (7000,0)};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
  \end{subfigure} 
\end{figure}
\vfill
\end{document}
```