# Removing exponential numbers from pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I'm doing a horizontal bar chart, but in my x axis and in the number in each bar is exponential and I want a "normal" number.
How can I do that?

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xbar,
width=12cm, height=6cm, enlarge y limits=0.2,
xlabel={total de edifícios certificados},
xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
symbolic y coords={HQE, BREEAM, LEED, DGNB, Green Star, Living Building},
ytick=data,
nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
]
\addplot coordinates {(266000,HQE) (250000,BREEAM)(51700,LEED)(834,DGNB)(256,Green Star)(192,Living Building)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Does this question help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96347/32374

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  For future reference, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: darthbirth, not really. This question is all about the axis, while my problem envolves also the numbers on the side of the bars. See my last comment bellow Peter's answer.

Comment: @JanaynaOlenick As you can see, the same information is needed, just put in a different place :-) Glad Peter was able to help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `scaled x ticks=false` to remove the scaling on the x axis. If you also want to elimiante the scaling on the labels for the bars you can use `every node near coord/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed}`:

[image]

### Notes:

- I also added `xmax=310000` to get the numbers within the box.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xbar,
width=12cm, height=6cm, enlarge y limits=0.2,
xlabel={total de edifícios certificados},
xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
symbolic y coords={HQE, BREEAM, LEED, DGNB, Green Star, Living Building},
ytick=data,
nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
scaled x ticks=false,
every node near coord/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
xmax=310000,
]
\addplot coordinates {(266000,HQE) (250000,BREEAM)(51700,LEED)(834,DGNB)(256,Green Star)(192,Living Building)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about the "number in each horizontal bar"?

Comment: Thanks Peter, that solves the axis problem. But you see the two last bars? Those are still using scientific notation. Any more suggestions?

Comment: @JanaynaOlenick: See revised solution. Sorry that I missed that in the original answer -- I should learn to read questions more carefully :-)