# how to format the values of the pgfplots axes

Tags: pgfplots

you can see in the picture above that the values of the abscissa range from 0,05 to 0,4.
how to do for the first value is 0.05 and not 5.10 ^ {- 2}?[image]

Comment: Does this help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96347/pgfplots-number-format-on-axis ? Seems duplicate to me

Comment: How about a MWE? Anyway, `/pgf/number format/fixed` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As TonioElGringo already stated in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418079/how-to-format-the-values-of-the-pgfplots-axes#comment1045749_418079) one possibility is to state `/pgf/number format/fixed` which forces all numbers to be displayed in "fixed" format.

In addition I show another method which results in the same result, but also shows *why* 0.05 by default is shown in scientific notation.

For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,
        xmax=0.25,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=0.25,
        xticklabel style={
            % either change the number format to fixed
            % regardless of the magnitude of the shown number ...
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
        },
        yticklabel style={
            % or change the limits of the standard algorithm that `\pgfmathprintnumber'
            % uses. By default the values are `-1:4'. So all numbers smaller than
            % 10^-1 or larger than 10^4 will be displayed using `sci' notation
            % and `fixed' otherwise
            /pgf/number format/std=-2,
        },
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0.1,0.1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]